Issue with EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck, observed field is not yet updated
I am attempting to extend the TextMeshProUI with a custom implementation. I extended the editor with it so that I can track some changes
public class LocalizedTMP_UGUI : TextMeshProUGUI
{
    // Stripped code
    [SerializeField] private List<LocArgument> m_arguments;

    public void SetLocalizedText()
    {
        text = m_localizer.GetLocalization(m_localizationKey, m_arguments);
        ForceMeshUpdate();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class LocArgument 
{
    public string name; 
    public string value;

    public LocArgument(string name, string value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

And for the editor part:
[CustomEditor(typeof(LocalizedTMP_UGUI))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class LocalizedTMP_UGUI_Editor : TMP_EditorPanelUI, ITMPEditor
{
    private SerializedProperty m_arguments;
    private string [] m_languages; 
    private int m_languageIndex = 0;
    private ILocalization m_localizer;

    // removed OnEnable

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        int languageIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(m_languageIndex, m_languages);
        if (languageIndex != m_languageIndex) 
        {
            m_localizer.SetWithLocale(m_languages[languageIndex]);
            SetText();
            m_languageIndex = languageIndex; 
        }
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(m_arguments);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            SetText();
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }

    public void SetText() 
    {
        LocalizedTMP_UGUI targetComp = (LocalizedTMP_UGUI)target;
        targetComp.SetLocalizedText();
        Repaint();
    }
}

When I switch the setting in the EditorGUILayout.Popup, it does the refresh of the text. But if I change the content of the arguments list (value field), it won't affect the displayed text in scene nor the text field of the component. Though if interacting with the inspector (folding/unfolding the list for example) then it refreshes and displays properly.
I have noticed that when debugging the SetLocalizedText method, text gets assigned with one letter delay. So if I start typing "Hello" then when entering the H, it shows "", then next entering the e, it will show "H", then "He" when typing the l and so on. And even though the text property gets set, it won't update the text field in the inspector until fiddling with the component.

This is likely due to mixing direct access with serialized object access.  The serializedObject is a snapshot of the object using reflection, set when calling Update.  Anything you change manually (without using serialized object methods) after calling update is not in the serialized object.  So setting the text directly on the target is not reflected in the serialized object.  You can: change where you call update, set the text via serialized object properties, or do all via manual assignment.

Thanks for that, it got me in the right direction!

I had two issues, first, based on comment, was that I was setting the text field while it needs to be the serialized property.
private SerializedProperty m_text;

protected override void OnEnable()
{
    m_text = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_text");
}
public void SetText() 
{
    LocalizedTMP_UGUI targetComp = (LocalizedTMP_UGUI)target;
    m_text.stringValue = m_localizer.GetLocalization(targetComp.LocalizationKey, targetComp.Arguments.ToList());
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}

Secondary issue came with the following where the check returns true but the serialized object still needs to be udpated
if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
{
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    SetText();
}

ApplyModifiedProperty is usually placed at the end of the OnInspectorGUI but in this case, it is needed in the check to update the property before using it.

when you modify the target you will need to use either EditorUtility.SetDirty to mark this asset as dirty so your change will actually be saved when you hit ctrl + s ... or actually even Undo.RecordObject in order to properly support undo/redo as well and if it is potentially a prefab even PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications

=> you almost always rather want to go through SerialzedProperty and SerializedObject instead and not have to deal with these low level tools ;)
